# How to use Nokia Music Api in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am used following code to get Genre using `Nokia Music API`.

```
 client.GetGenres((ListResponse<Genre> response) =>
 {
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
     {
       this.Generic.ItemsSource = response.Result.ToList();
       if (response.Result == null || response.Result.Count() == 0)
           MessageBox.Show("No Result available");
     });
  });
```

I am successfully getting the `genre` and all details but how can i retrieve the all tracks and play the selected one Track.

Comment: get the selected index from the list and suitably write your code to play the file from the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Nokia Developer API Documentation](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!nokia-music-apis/utilizing-nokia-music-api-music-explorer-example-application.html;#toc_Makingrequests)

In order to play a specific artist use the nokia API Music Launcher

> The following method from Music Explorer's MusicApi shows how simple
>   it is to launch Nokia Music application to play artist mix. Nokia
>   Music app can be launched just as easily into a product or artist
>   state using Nokia Music API. Some of the launcher methods in Nokia
>   Music API require unique ids of artists, mixes and products. These ids
>   are received in responses from Nokia Music API's other services.

```
using Nokia.Music.Phone;
using Nokia.Music.Phone.Tasks;

...

namespace MusicExplorer
{
    ...

    public class MusicApi
    {
        ...

        public void LaunchArtistMix(string artistName)
        {
            ...

            PlayMixTask task = new PlayMixTask();
            task.ArtistName = artistName;
            task.Show();
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

I don't see anything specifc about listing album contents but you can probably leverage `GetArtistProducts()` to do this

```
client.GetArtistProducts(
  (ListResponse<Product> response) =>
  {
    // Use results
  },
```

Comment: i used above code in my application but i am not successfully get the tracks and tracks URI.

Comment: @user2711213 We are not miracle workers here. You need to post more code or an error or something that can help. This code DOES work. It's off of the Nokia Developer API site. If it's not working for you then either you miss-interpret what it does, or you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @AMR Nokia music is no longer available. How can you register to get the app id now? Any idea?

Comment: @max you should just need a Nokia Developer API Key I am note 100% sure but I think its universal for all their services now  https://sso.developer.nokia.com/login?immediatereq=true&locale=en&state=13359F8C9A14797867393345002723204102881407

Comment: @AMR They have removed Nokia music recently.That's the problem